# Linq returning specific type

Tags: c#, linq

How do you return a specific type in a Linq query? I know you can use ToList() to return a list of specific objects but how do you return a non list?

```
MyObj x = from x in list where x.id == 99 select x;
```

Comment: You're using the words "specific type" to mean "instance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyObj x = list.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.id == 99);
```

Alternative `IEnumerable` methods you can use to return a single item:

- `list.Single(i=>i.id == 99)`: throws an exception if no matches are found or multiple matches are found.
- `list.SingleOrDefault(i=>i.id == 99)`: returns null if no matches are found, throws an exception if multiple matches are found.
- `list.First(i=>i.id == 99)`: throws an exception if no matches are found. If multiple matches are found, returns the first item in the list.
- `list.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.id == 99)`: returns null if no matches are found. If multiple matches are found, returns the first item in the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
MyObj x = (from x in list where x.id == 99 select x).Single();
```

if you expect that the id might not exist, then you could use SingleOrDefault to return the default value for the type (probably null in this case).

You could, of course, use First() but I'd be wary, as this could hide errors if you expect to only have one item returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyObj x = list.Where(x => x.id == 99).FirstOrDefault();
```